# How do I increase Threads per core for an Ubuntu VM in VMware?

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, central-processing-unit, ubuntu-22.04

I recently purchased a VMware dedicated server and I created my first VPS on it with Ubuntu 22 server OS . Using lscpu in Ubuntu , I'm seeing the following :

```
steam@steam:/root$ lscpu
Architecture:            x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:         45 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                  8
  On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Vendor ID:               GenuineIntel
  Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v4 @ 3.20GHz
    CPU family:          6
    Model:               79
    Thread(s) per core:  1
    Core(s) per socket:  4
    Socket(s):           2
    Stepping:            1
    BogoMIPS:            6392.59
    Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc cpuid tsc_kno
                         wn_freq pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp fsgsbase tsc_a
                         djust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 invpcid rdseed adx smap xsaveopt arat md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities
Virtualization features:
  Hypervisor vendor:     VMware
  Virtualization type:   full
Caches (sum of all):
  L1d:                   256 KiB (8 instances)
  L1i:                   256 KiB (8 instances)
  L2:                    2 MiB (8 instances)
  L3:                    50 MiB (2 instances)
NUMA:
  NUMA node(s):          1
  NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7
Vulnerabilities:
  Gather data sampling:  Not affected
  Itlb multihit:         KVM: Mitigation: VMX unsupported
  L1tf:                  Mitigation; PTE Inversion
  Mds:                   Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT Host state unknown
  Meltdown:              Mitigation; PTI
  Mmio stale data:       Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT Host state unknown
  Retbleed:              Mitigation; IBRS
  Spec rstack overflow:  Not affected
  Spec store bypass:     Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp
  Spectre v1:            Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
  Spectre v2:            Mitigation; IBRS, IBPB conditional, STIBP disabled, RSB filling, PBRSB-eIBRS Not affected
  Srbds:                 Not affected
  Tsx async abort:       Not affected
```

How do I increase Threads per core ?

Comment: Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User, and questions about development, testing and development tools may be asked on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

You don't. ESXi passes the number of vCPUs forward and they are virtualized, while the host manages the cores and hyperthreading itself. The host will show all threads instead of simply physical cores. There is no way to pass hyperthreading specifically to a VM, just more vCPUs

If you need more threads, you want to add vCPUs under edit in the VM (you will probably need to shut down the VM to do this).

Comment: Based on VMware knowledge base , I think I must enable hyperthreading in vmware as well . there is an option called " VMkernel.Boot.hyperthreading " which needs to be set to true . I checked from BIOS actually hyperthreading is enabled but I'm not sure about VMware . Need to check this .

Comment: You can do that, but it will hobble the way VMware schedules vCPU usage. Until I hear better info from VMware regarding their architecture, best practices will mean not doing this with out a specific reason.
Apparently, in ESXi 6.5 it was made more difficult to override vNUMA scheduling but it can be done, as you illustrate.
Ubuntu will likely perform worse after doing this - unless you require less cores to the OS to license an app, I wouldn't do it. Ubuntu doesn't need it.
https://blogs.vmware.com/performance/2017/03/virtual-machine-vcpu-and-vnuma-rightsizing-rules-of-thumb.html